# How is a server certificate validated in SSL?

Tags: ssl, x509

Let's say server S sends it's certificate to client C. What is the method used to validate that this certificate is authentic?

What are the steps carried out to ensure that this is indeed the certificate issue to server S by a CA ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The server sends a digital signature over the handshake data, signed by the private key coresponding to the public key in the certificate. The client verifies the signature with the public key. That establishes that the server owns the private key.
2. The client attempts to establish a trust relationship between the CAs that it trusts and the IssuerDN chain of the certificate. If successful, that establishes that the chain of CAs all believe in the next one's identity all the way to the SubjectDN of the certificate.

So at this point we know that the server owns the private key implied by the certificate's public key, and that the owner of the certificate is who it says he is. So now we know who he is.

Comment: thank you for the answer. One more question, how does the client try to establish this trust relationship ?  

Also, this public key in the certificate belongs to the CA or the server ? If it is the CA that signs the certificate, it should be the public key of the CA right ?

Comment: AFAIK, point 1 is for DH(E) key exchange. For RSA key exchange, it works with encryption, not signature, where the server is the only one capable of deciphering the pre-master secret. Same result, though.

Comment: @Bruno RFC 2246 calls them digital signatures in both cases.

Comment: In RSA key exchange (F.1.1.2), don't signatures only refer to optional temporary keys and client-cert auth only? Otherwise, in most cases (no temporary RSA key, no client cert), I don't think the server signs anything with the private key for its cert, it only deciphers the premaster key from the client key exchange message (which only it can do). I can't see any ref to digital signatures in that context (even in 7.4.7.1). Maybe I've missed something (it's getting late)...